# Avoid duplicate values using join with multiple tables in Firebird

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I have 3 tables

Payments

| PaymntID | Date | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ago.2021 | 500 |
| 2 | Sep.2021 | 1200 |
| 3 | Oct.2021 | 600 |

CashPayments

| PaymntID | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 500 |
| 2 | 400 |
| 3 | 200 |

CreditCardPayments

| PaymntID | Amount | CreditCard |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 450 | Visa |
| 2 | 350 | MC |
| 3 | 400 | Visa |

I need to get the PaymentID, date, amount payed in cash and amount payed in creditcard, but with the following query I'm getting duplicates.

Just a quick note, I can have two different credit cards used in one payment, but I can also have 2 different "cash payments" used in one payment.

Query:

```sql
select
PA.DATE AS PaymntDate,
PA.PaymntID AS PaymntID,
CP.amount AS CashAmount,
CCP.amount AS CreditAmount,

from Payments PA
    LEFT join CashPayments CP on PA.PaymntID = CP.PaymntID
    LEFT join CreditCardPayments CCP on PA.PaymntID = CCP.PaymntID
```

I'm getting the following result:

Result

| PaymntID | PaymntDate | CashAmount | CreditAmount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ago.2021 | 500 | null |
| 2 | Sep.2021 | 400 | 450 |
| 2 | Sep.2021 | 400 | 350 |
| 3 | Oct.2021 | 200 | 400 |

So in this case, the cashpayment in paymntid 2 is duplicated. What I need is the following table:

Result

| PaymntID | PaymntDate | CashAmount | CreditAmount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ago.2021 | 500 | null |
| 2 | Sep.2021 | 400 | 800 |
| 3 | Oct.2021 | 200 | 400 |

Comment: Hint: `GROUP BY`, `SUM()`.

Comment: I tried, but I would have to use the sum() function on both the cash and the credit card payments. When I tried that option, I get "800" as cashamount (id 2) in the result table.

Comment: GROUP BY in a derived table (subquery), _before_ joining!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to aggregate the values for each ID *before* joining. Probably the most succinct way is to use a CTE and then outer join each to your *payments* table, something like the following:

```
with cp as (
  select paymentId, Sum(Amount) Amount
  from CashPayments
  group by PaymentId
), ccp as (
  select paymentId, Sum(Amount) QAmount
  from CreditCardPayments
  group by PaymentId 
)
select p.PaymentId, p.Date,
  Coalesce(cp.Amount,0) CashAmount,
  Coalesce(ccp.Amount,0) CreditAmount
from Payments p
left join cp on cp.PaymentId = p.PaymentId
left join ccp on ccp.PaymentId = p.PaymentId
```

Comment: Thank you very much, works perfectly! just a question, If I need to add a condition to bring data from one of the tables. i.e. cp.sellerid = 'abc' where should I write it?
Here:
```sql
with cp as (
  select paymentId, Sum(Amount) Amount
  from CashPayments
  where CashPayments.sellerid = 'abc'
  group by PaymentId
),
``` 
or here:
```sql
left join cp on cp.PaymentId = p.PaymentId and cp.sellerid = 'abc'
``` 

Thanks again!

Comment: There's no `SellerId` in your question so hard to say, depends on if you are fitering a specific `SellerId` or want to include all, so you'd include it in the CTE and include in the `group by` and  possibly `join` criteria - depends on the data.

Comment: Sorry, in the real db the cashpayments table has more columns, so the question would be what if I need to get the data only where certain condition is met, like sellerid = 'abc'. I included that clause inside the subquery as "where cashpayments.sellerid = 'abc' and worked. Now I'm checking the data to see if I'm getting the correct amounts considering that criteria.

Comment: If you're unable to successfully apply this to your real-world scenario then by all means ask it as a new question with the additional information and criteria.